# Obtain the name of a list as column in dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr

I am having trouble to extract the the name of a list in a dataframe.

My nested list is as following:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

category <- list(fruits<-c("apples","orange", "pear","banana","strawberries"),
vegetables<-c("cauliflower","potato","onion","tomato"),
dairy<-c("goats milk", "cows milk"))
```

My dataframe:

```
column1<-c("apples","potato","onion","goats milk")
df<-as.data.frame(column1)


final<-df%>%mutate(listname=column1%in%category)
```

I get following result:

```
      column1 listname

1     apples    FALSE
2     potato    FALSE
3      onion    FALSE
4 goats milk    FALSE
```

What I wish to have is:

```
      column1 listname

1     apples    fruit
2     potato    vegetable
3      onion    vegetable
4 goats milk    dairy
```

Truly appreciate your help.

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
merge(df,stack(category),by.x = "column1",by.y= "values")
     column1        ind
1     apples     fruits
2 goats milk      dairy
3      onion vegetables
4     potato vegetables
```

But first ensure that you have categories as shown below:

```
category <- list(fruits=c("apples","orange", "pear","banana","strawberries"),
vegetables=c("cauliflower","potato","onion","tomato"),
dairy=c("goats milk", "cows milk"))
```

You can also use:

```
library(dplyr) 
left_join(df,stack(category),c("column1"="values"))
```